# Xlwings is moving the cell value up itself

Tags: excel, xlwings

When I re-run the calculations in Excel or Python. The value in a specific cell moves up itself. I didn't program that.

What may be the issue?

```
sheet.range("B23").value = ["Metal walls (Carbon steel), kM", 54, "W/m.K"]
```

The output after the fourth run is attached.
[duplicate values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oXSs.png)

Comment: @BigBen Other lines of code are working fine. Just this line. Does this kind of problem occur often?

Comment: [Perhaps useful](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#lists).